# Java Map of List ( Map<String, List<String>>) to Angular

Tags: angular

I am returning Java HashMap from Controller Map<String, List>

Data is below -

```
{A=[X,Y,Z], B=[P,Q]}
```

In Angular, I want to display like this -

```
A
    X
    Y
    Z
B
    P
    Q
```

I tried with this piece of code -

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let first of content | keyvalue">
        {{first.key}}
        <div *ngFor="let second of first.value">
            {{second}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I am getting "Failed to compile." error.

---

If I use below code-

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let first of content | keyvalue">
        {{first.key}} --> {{first.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting below output-

```
A --> X,Y,Z
B --> P,Q
```

I need values inside the list in separate lines. Any help would be appreciated!

PS - I do not want to process data in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <div *ngFor="let first of content | keyvalue">
      {{first.key}}
      <div style="margin-left:25px" *ngFor="let val of content[first.key]">
        {{val}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let first of content | keyvalue">
    {{first.key}}
    <div *ngFor="let val of content.get(first.key)">
        {{val}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @vinS fixed the answer. It works in case if "content" is a Map<string, string[]>

Comment: My question is not about `Map<string, string[]>`